# member function LinkedList::deleteNode may not be redeclared

Tags: c++, pointers, private, public, member-functions

I've been trying to fix this error member function LinkedList::deleteNode may not be redeclared outside its class over and over again. I already made sure each member function has two } at the end of every member function, I also made sure it's not being declared elsewhere and I continue to get the same error. The other errors I am getting are:

expected a ';'
expected a declaration
'LinkedList::deleteNode': local definitions are illegal 
'{':no matching token found

Thank you so much for your guidance! [LinkedList with pointers](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H4eCOK6Gf2Pkpu9Qunz4QT131NKa5K8C2lj9KpAhzM4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. And this: [mcve]. And post your code here not as a link. And "LinkedList.h" is missing from your link.

Comment: Please add sufficient information to the question, for example some code

Comment: looks like you are missing a `}` somewhere in your code..

Answer (score 0):

`}` is missing at the end of `insertNode` and at the end of `deleteNode`.

Comment: Hey there Jabberwocky, thank you very much for your help. I went ahead and added } to the end of insertNode and deleteNode and it looks like it got rid of the problem.